# Develop Regular Expression that every A is followed by a B

Tags: regex

I want to develop a regular expression that has the following features:

1. Every "A" is followed by a "B", what I thought about this was that we can have (A[C-Z]*B)+
2. B is not required to present immediately present after A. That being said, ACCB is also okay.
3. When there's multiple A's present, same number of B's should also present. This makes it a bit tricky, as AABB, AAABBB, AXXXBAXXB, AXXAXXBXXAXXBXXB should also be okay. I got stuck on this.
4. Only capital letters are allowed.

Accepted Strings:
AABB

AXXBAXXB

AXXXXBXXAXXB

ABABABABAB

NOT ACCEPTED:

AAAAB

AABBBB

BBBBAAAA

AXXXBBBAAA

I appreciate any help given.

Comment: Please add a list of acceptable and non acceptable matches

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reminder, and yes, it has to be a regex.

Comment: I have tried (A[C-Z]*B)+, which doesn't work when there's more or less number of B's than A's.

Comment: Don't use a regex. Remember what JWZ said: "Some people, when they have a problem, say 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: Part 3 can't be done using standard regexp, they recognize balanced patterns. It can be done using the recursion extension in PCRE.

Comment: PCRE: [`\b(?:[^AB\s]*(A(?>[^AB\s]+|(?1))*B))+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/kV3gR4/1), [PHP code demo](https://ideone.com/C3Lz5T). The `[^AB\s]*` might be necessary before the last `\b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the OP says it has to be a regex, but I agree with @tbodt's comment above.  This will accomplish what the OP is asking for without a regex and is posted here for anyone trying to solve a similar problem and is open to a different type of solution.

```
function everyAHasMatchingB(str) {
    return Array.from(str)
                .filter(c => c === 'A' || c === 'B')
                .reduce((count, aOrB) => {
                    return aOrB === 'A' ? count + 1 :
                           count <= 0   ? NaN // Mismatched B.  NaN ensures the function returns false.
                                        : count - 1
                }, 0) === 0;
}
```